# Accepted a seasonal job position, but haven't heard back on when to start

Tags: interviewing

So, I decided to pick up a job at the book store at my local community college, since I am going back to college I figured it would be perfect. Since its only seasonal I would have to find another job at college or close by. During the interview I was told it would be from August 3rd to August 24th. They didn't even start the background check until last Thursday, and that made me worry that I won't be starting on Aug. 3rd. I have sent a email, and left a voicemail for the lady that gave me the interview, and I haven't heard back from her. I don't know how I could have failed background check, I owe some money to my college, and I plan to pay that before starting, could that be a reason not to hire me?

How should I proceed about this? Should I leave another voicemail? I mean I have bills that need to be paid and a week out of work will hit pretty hard.

Comment: Could be but I was offered the position, and told them I would take it. I went/in background progress but I didn't think it would take this long.

Comment: Until you have a concrete start date, I would consider the offer tentative. Continue to follow-up on your other job leads until you get an offer that includes a concrete start date. If this company calls you in the meantime, then you always have the chance to go with them. But if they don't get back to you, don't be stuck with no job.

Answer (score 1):

> How should I proceed about this? Should I leave another voicemail?

Since you already sent an email, and left a voicemail, and since it's already after August 3rd, your best bet is to just show up at the book store and talk to someone in person.

It would have been better to do that before August 3rd, but the next best thing is to show up today. The longer you wait, the fewer possible workdays remain.